# Switch case not working in turbo c compiler

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch;
    float a, b, c;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter value of a");
    scanf ("%f", &a);
    printf("enter value if b");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf(" a for addition");
    printf("b for sub");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 'a':
        c = a + b;
        printf("addition=%f", c);
        break ;
    case 'b':
        c = a - b;
        printf("\nsubtraction=%f", c);
        break;
    default :
        printf ("wrong choice");
    }
    getch();
}
```

This is the result what i get:
**enter value of a4
enter value if b4
 a for additionb for subwrong choice**

the problem is switch condition not evaluated even once..
compile:turbo c on windows

Comment: You might try printing the value of `ch` immediately before the `switch` (hint: print it as an `int` and have an ASCII table handy). Also, **Turbo C**? Really? You're using a compiler that's most likely **older than you**!

Comment: Try to find a compiler that is not so outdated. Give Visual C++ Express a chance.

Comment: Also, this code is written like old C, with no variable initialization. And why would you make the user type "a" for + and "b" for minus?

Comment: Always check return values of *scanf* functions and handle parse errors (like, just exit if nothing else). Debugging any code like this without doing that is pointless.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Do not forget to take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) which will give you some guideline on how to work here :)

Comment: C or C++? **PICK ONE**

Answer (score 3):

Flush your input buffer to consume `\n` left in the buffer.
Or try this

```
 scanf(" %c",&ch);  
        ^
        | A space before %c can skip any number of whitespaces
```